# How can I export test cases in HP ALM to be re-imported into another ALM project?

Tags: test-management, test-strategy, quality-center, legacy-system

I've been put on a new project, which has some `legacy test cases`, these test cases exist in `ALM`. I would like to export certain sections of this test plan for usage in the new project, which again exists in `ALM`. Both of these projects exist on the same server, but on different domains.

Is there a simple way I can `export the test cases` I want from one `ALM project` to another?  I need the tests, their steps, any attachments etc.  I basically just want exactly what exists in the test plan section, to be ported across to a different project.

I've already looked at similar questions, exporting to excel without test steps, attachments etc is a no go.  Exporting to a report is no go, because I need to import the data.

Has anyone done this before?  I'm using the latest `ALM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hilariously the answer to this is copy and paste!  You can use Tools -> Change Project to navigate between projects.  Simply right click what you wish to migrate, copy, change project and paste where you desire!

You will have to decide what to do with related entities when copying across.